# Firebase Functions throw function with internal error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a project under Firebase Hosting with Firebase Functions.
Index.js:

```
exports.simpleFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return data;
});
```

Index.html:

```
var simpleFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('simpleFunction');
    
simpleFunction("12").then (function(result) {
                                    console.log(result);
                                }).catch(function(error) {
                                    console.log("Error code:" + error.code);
                                });
```

In console I only get:

"Error code: Internal"

Could anybody help me figure out what happens?

Comment: What version of the Firebase client SDK are you working with?  What do the error logs on the functions console say?

Comment: OMG!!!!
The version vas 7.21.1, which I had to change to 8.0.0.
Thanx a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario on my project and your code works as expected, this is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>
    <script  src="/__/firebase/8.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script  src="/__/firebase/8.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script  src="/__/firebase/8.0.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script  src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

    <style media="screen">

    </style>
</head>
<body>

Hello world!!


</body>

<script>html
    let simpleFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('simpleFunction');

    simpleFunction("12").then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error code:" + error.code);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I'm using latest firebase web packages and my function supports [unauthenticated access](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation).

**Update I was able to reproduce this issue**

I tried to invoke another function (python function) but since firebase-functions package doesn't exists on python, this looks the root cause, try to update your firebase-functions package or try with my reproduction example.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"  
  }
}
```

**function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


exports.simpleFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It was about the version I used...
Now it's working! :)

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me a lot of frustration :D