# Firebase https function return "internal error" when called

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call an https firebase function from my code.
The issue is that when called my function return an error with code `internal` the error message is also  `internal`. I tried to search online for this issue the one thing i found on the firebase doc describing this error code is that something is very wrong. So i'm pretty confused.
This is how the function is called :

```
export const getPlanDetails = (plan: string) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  try {
  
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR,
      payload: null,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: IS_FETCHING,
      payload: true,
    });
    const request = functions.httpsCallable("getPlanDetails");
    const response = await request({ plan: plan });

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PLAN_DETAIL,
      payload: {
        currency: response.data["currency"],
        name: response.data["name"],
        interval: response.data["interval"],
        amount: response.data["amount"],
      },
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch({
      type: ERROR,
      payload: "An error occured getting the plan details",
    });
  } finally {
    dispatch({
      type: IS_FETCHING,
      payload: false,
    });
  }
};
```

This is the screen of the error message that is returned:
[image]

I can confirm that the issue do not come from my function beacause when i call it on another project it works just fine. Thus i also checked that the function is uploaded to google could from my firebase console. It also could not be my function thaty is failing beacause i setup custom error messages when it happens.

This is the function code :

```
exports.getPlanDetails = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const plan = await stripe.plans.retrieve(data.plan);
    return {
      currency: plan["currency"],
      name: plan["nickname"],
      interval: plan["interval"],
      amount: plan["amount"],
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    await reportError(error, { user: context.auth.uid });
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("something went wrong ...", error);
  }
});
```

This is how i init the `functions` var :

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { store } from "../redux";
import { AUTH_STATE_CHANGE } from "../redux/types/auth.type";

const firebaseConfig = {
//secret
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const functions = firebase.functions();


export { auth, firestore, functions };
```

I think firebase is well initialized beaucause other services like auth or firestore are working fine

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you pls show the exact output of `console.log(error);` in the Cloud Functions log? Also, note that the first argument of `functions.https.HttpsError()` shall have one of the values listed at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror. `something went wrong ...` is not a correct value. See also https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

Comment: Thanks. What I would actually like to see is the log of the Cloud Function execution, i.e. what was printed by the `console.log()`. You can find the Cloud Function log in the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com). Open the "Functions" menu item and click on the "Logs" tab. Also, did you try changing `functions.https.HttpsError("something went wrong ...", error);` with a correct code?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I cheked the console and in fact the function is not called at all. So the issue must come from the client side

Comment: Ok, so do you see any error in the client side? Can you show the **entire** code of your client side? Do you catch errors there?

Comment: I see your question update. Is the `console.log()` in the `catch` block executed?? Also, how do you declare `functions`that is used at `functions.httpsCallable`?

Comment: PS: Are you sure the Cloud Function is not called? You mention in your question that you received an error of type internal.

Comment: First i updated my post and added how i init the functions var. I also double checked and i'm sure that the function is not called and precisely that is why i'm pretty confused too with the error message.

Comment: The `functions` var is indeed correctly initiated. Without more debug details, I’m afraid I can’t help you more.

Comment: Could you please specify your **Firebase SDK** version?

Comment: I found these threads where the issue was related to the Firebase SDK version (7.22.0 and lower): [link1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3890), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560828/firebase-functions-throw-function-with-internal-error).